# How can I "limit" the page numbers of a forum/blog in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to fix something with which I'm not familiar with and don't know how to proceed. The forum on which I'm working is suppose to show under  "TOP 50" only the most commented topics (2 pages by 25 topics) but it shows all topics (by 25) without any limitation of the pages. I need only the first 2 pages - but don't know how to get rid of the others?

I'm even not sure that the below code is the responsible one but please have a look and give me a hint if you see any solution.

This is the code:

```
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_forum()
    {
        if ($_GET['l'] && ($_GET['l'] == 'leng' || $_GET['l'] == 'lrus' || $_GET['l'] == 'lde' || $_GET['l'] == 'ltr'))
            $l = substr($_GET['l'], 1);
        else
            $l = 'eng';

        (isset($_GET['num'])) ? $page = intval($_GET['num']) : $page = 1;

        $id_user = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
        $lang = language::getLang();

        if ($_GET['el']) {
            switch ($_GET['el']) {
            case 'categories':
                return $this->getCategories($l);
                break;
            case 'top':
                $top_lang = $_GET['ln'];

                $c = $this->db->selectAssoc($this->db->Select('*', 'forum_categories ,forum_thems', "`forum_categories`.`lang` = '" . $l
                . "' AND `forum_thems`.`id_categories` = `forum_categories`.`id`"));
                $total_pages = count($c) / 25;
                $p = "<div class=\"pageCounter_box\">Pages:";

                if (empty($_GET['p'])) {
                    $_GET['p'] = 1;
                }

                for($i=1; $i<$total_pages+1; $i++){
                    if ($i == $_GET['p']) {
                        $class = 'class="active_page"';
                    }
                    $p .= "<a href=\"$top_lang/smoke/{$_GET['l']}/top?p=$i\" $class>$i</a>";
                }
                $p .= "</div>";
                return $this->getTop($l) . $p;
                break;
```

Comment: I think you could do a check in there of
 If ($total_pages > 2) { $total_pages = 2};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do a check in there of If ($total_pages > 2) { $total_pages = 2};

```
  $c = $this->db->selectAssoc(
     $this->db->Select('*', 'forum_categories ,forum_thems', "`forum_categories`.
                       `lang` = '" . $l. "' AND `forum_thems`.
                       `id_categories` = `forum_categories`.`id`"));
  $total_pages = count($c) / 25;
  if ($total_pages >2) { //limit to two pages
      $total_pages = 2;
  }
  $p = "<div class=\"pageCounter_box\">Pages:";
  if (empty($_GET['p'])) {
    $_GET['p'] = 1;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Seth, thanks a lot - great help! Do you further see why both pages might show active (page counter shows both active) when showing page 1? Page 2 is fine, there only Page 2 shows active...

Answer (score -1):

"thanks a lot - great help! Do you further see why both pages might show active (page counter shows both active) when showing page 1? Page 2 is fine, there only Page 2 shows active..."

The $class variable is staying set, you need to have an else that sets the class to an empty string

```
  for($i=1; $i<$total_pages+1; $i++){
    if ($i == $_GET['p']) {
      $class = 'class="active_page"';
    } else {
      $class = '';
    }
    $p .= "<a href=\"$top_lang/smoke/{$_GET['l']}/top?p=$i\" $class>$i</a>";
  }
```

Comment: You should delete this answer and instead edit your original answer.

Comment: Nah... its a different issue. What difference does it make to you anyways?

Comment: Hi Seth, thanks so much - you solved my porblem! I was trying to accept both answers but I can "click" on only one at the time... But thanks again!